# how to Include a folder and files in META-INF folder when creating the jar using ant task

Tags: ant

I need a way to include a folders and files inside the META-INF directory when creating a jar using ant task.

Currrently I am using `<metainf>` tag , which is only including the files but not the folders.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: What if you just use the copy task? ---> https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html       something like this ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185469/copy-entire-directory-before-creating-an-ear-file    it's probably you can find a better way to do this, but like i'm saying works for sure :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Add new folder `TEMP-INF` under `src\main\java`
2. Put all the files and folders, which you wish to include in your JAR's META-INF into this newly created `TEMP-INF`
3. Now open `build.xml` file and search for 
   `<jar> </jar>` tag
4. Add `<metainf dir="src/main/java/TEMP-INF"/>` into `<jar></jar>`
5. And its done.